# Python Multiprocessing Simplequeue method gives weird result

Tags: python

The following code should give a list **[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]** but instead, it **generates a new list sequence every time such** as [4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3, 5, 1] also sometimes **it could not stop automatically**.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, SimpleQueue, freeze_support


def func_1(data_rcv_1, data_snd_2):
    while not data_rcv_1.empty():
        inp = data_rcv_1.get()
        data_snd_2.put(inp)
    data_snd_2.close()


def func_2(data_rcv_2):
    lst = []
    while not data_rcv_2.empty():
        inp = data_rcv_2.get()
        lst.append(inp)
    print(lst)


def main():
    data_snd_1 = data_snd_2 = SimpleQueue()
    mp_func_1 = Process(target=func_1, args=(data_snd_1, data_snd_2))
    mp_func_2 = Process(target=func_2, args=(data_snd_2,))
    mp_func_1.daemon = True
    mp_func_2.daemon = True
    mp_func_1.start()
    mp_func_2.start()

    for i in range(1, 10):
        data_snd_1.put(i)
    data_snd_1.close()
    mp_func_1.join()
    mp_func_2.join()
    mp_func_1.terminate()
    mp_func_2.terminate()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    main()
```

Can somebody explain the right way of doing this (if I'm doing something wrong)?

Answer (score 0):

It's a timing problem. You start both functions synchronously and it kind of starts a race between both of them which is not always won by the right function causing problems. If you put a  `time.sleep(1)` between `mp_func_1.start()` and `mp_func_2.start()` it works for me.
I'm just a beginner so this might not be the perfect solution or the best explanation but that's what I found out.